# Windows 10 suddenly started using "SYSTEM" as my %username%

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry

My Windows 10 machine has started behaving oddly after what may have been a failed automatic update. When I logged in, I got error messages from several programs that they couldn't find files they expected to find in `%AppData%`. My desktop was also empty aside from the recycle bin. After some digging around, I have determined that somehow the `%USERNAME%` and `%USERPROFILE%` variables, at least, are set incorrectly. The username is `SYSTEM`, and my profile is being stored in `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile`. Weirdly, though, PowerShell at least seems to default to running in the proper user directory for me:

[image: powershell showing wrong variables]

Any programs I run seem to have never "met" me before, i.e. they need to be reconfigured, and when I do so they store their configuration in this system profile, which is obviously not a good thing to do long-term. I can't even run `cmd`, because it tries to read some kind of settings from AppData first. Hence the above image of cluelessly flailing around in PowerShell.

As far as I can see, the directory storing my real profile is fine: `C:\Users\amalloy` has all the stuff I would expect to see, including an AppData directory. The closest cousin to this problem I can find on superuser is [Windows 7 x64 %userprofile% and %username% are wrong](https://superuser.com/questions/451045/windows-7-x64-userprofile-and-username-are-wrong), from quite a while ago. Similar, but not the same. First of all, I don't receive a message at login telling me that it failed to load my profile and is giving me a temporary one. But, inspired by that question, I went looking around in the registry,  and their problem doesn't seem to be mine. My `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` doesn't have any `.bak` suffix, just the defaultuser0 profile and one whose ProfileImagePath is C:\Users\amalloy.

[image: ProfileList registry image]

Based on [another post I found on Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/userprofile-points-to/25ef3a00-b33c-4a6a-9a88-ee9128c17faf) I also checked the registry for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment`, in case it is pointing at the wrong thing, but it correctly thinks I am amalloy, and points to all the right directories for me.

[image: Volatile Environment registry image]

Of course, I have tried rebooting, but the problem persists. I would have liked to try a System Restore to yesterday's state, but I discovered today that the default System Restore setting for Windows 10 is "disabled", so I don't have any registry backups. A plausible fix that's been suggested is to create a new user and copy my files over to it. But I can't do this, because the "create another user" dialog just closes instantly - if I had to guess, it, too, is looking for something in AppData that it can't find.

Does anyone have suggested fixes, or next steps to investigate?

Comment: It's highly unlikely this was a result of an update, as `NT USER/SYSTEM` cannot be used to log in to Windows _(you can execute programs via `PSexec` as `NT USER/SYSTEM`, but you cannot log in as `NT USER/SYSTEM` - even with the `auditSystem`/`auditUser` install phase, default `Administrator` account is used)_, which means a few things could have occurred, such as the username being changed to `SYSTEM`, environment variables corruption, user profile corruption, etc. The way to fix would have been to create a new user profile _(google for steps from Microsoft)_ then perform a Repair Install.

Comment: _(Please do not screenshot terminals - copy/paste their content into a code box - and please ensure `monospaced code` is specified as such, else it doesn't translate correctly)_ Variables with `%<var>%` are Cmd variables only, whereas PowerShell variables use `$` and environment variables are prefaced with `$env:` - to have PowerShell `echo` a Cmd variable, preface it with `cmd /c` || `cmd /k` [`cmd /c echo %UserProfile%`]

Comment: @JW0914 As mentioned, I tried creating a new profile, but that dialog closed the instant I opened it. But I didn't try doing it from `mmc` - maybe that would have worked.

Comment: There are a myriad of ways for creating a new user profile: using `net user`, enabling the default `Administrator` account, logging in to it, creating the new user, logging back out, and re-disable it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up and reinstalled Windows. Most of the recovery options I could find recommended would not work, much like many other programs I tried to run.

Comment: The way to fix would have been to [create](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-a-corrupted-user-profile-in-windows-1cf41c18-7ce3-12f9-8e1d-95896661c5c9) a new user profile, then perform a Repair Install _(Download the Media Creation tool from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) → Choose to install on another PC to save the `windows.iso` → extract ISO to folder on a partition other than `C:` → Launch `setup.exe` **while booted to Windows** → choose to keep all files and settings)_

Answer (score 0):

On my company's computer without all admin rights I see the same problem. The most pain point was Git which wanted to read a C:\Users\SYSTEM\ directory to store global config.
After overriding the system variable USERNAME with an account variable, my problem went away.